# Autowired implementation based on profile Spring Boot

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I am developing a REST API with Spring Boot.The problem it's that I have one interface and two implementations and I want to test only with the mock implementation.

```
Interface CRMService 

@Service
CRMServiceImpl

@Service
CRMServiceMock
```

**Implementations**: the first one is the real integration with the backend and the second is a mock for testing purposes, what's the best approach? Integration test or test based on the active profile ? If I need to autowire a service based on profile what's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm sure there's exceptions, generally it shouldn't be integration or unit tests (often involves mocks), but both; see testing pyramid concept.

Integration tests: just use the real service. If it calls out to other live services, then consider injecting the URLs as Spring Boot properties which point to mock servers in the test environment (Node.js or something easy and quick).

Unit tests: Consider using a test-framework like Mockito. Using this you can write your tests with mocks approximately like so:

```
private CRMServiceImpl mockService = mock(CRMServiceImpl.class);

@Test
public void someTest() {
    when(mockService.someMethod(any(String.class), eq(5))).thenReturn("Hello from mock object.")
}
```

The above example roughly translates to "when some class invokes 'someMethod(String, int)' on your service, return the String specified".

This way allows you to still use mocks where necessary, but avoids having to maintain entire mock implementation profiles and avoids the problem of what to auto-wire.

Finally, if you need a full separate implementation, consider not auto-wiring services! Instead, use `@Bean` annotations in your configuration class and inject it via constructors into the classes that need it. Something like so:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Value{$"service.crm.inmem"} // Injected property
    private boolean inMem;

    @Bean
    CRMService getCRMService() {
        if (inMem) {
            return new CRMServiceMock();
        }
        return new CRMServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    OtherService getOtherService() {
        // Inject CRMService interface into constructor instead of auto-wiring in OtherService.class
        return new OtherService(getCRMService());
    }
}
```

An example of when you could use ^^ would be if you wanted to switch between an in-memory store, and a real database-connection layer.

Personally I'd suggest doing dependency injection like the above example even when there aren't multiple implementations since as a project grows, if an auto-wired property fails it can be difficult to track down exactly why. Additionally explicitly showing where dependencies come from can help with organizing your application and visualizing your application hierarchy.

Comment: I believe Profiles would handle it also in a bit cleaner way (what you have posted with inMem variable).

Comment: @SirKometa Yes, that's true, though I suppose it would depend on the number of variations you wish to have. If only a few, then perhaps profiles; if many, then manipulating individual values might be easier than enumerating all the profiles necessary.